# Energy source for phase transformation-latent heat of vapourisation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, gas

As per my knowledge, phase transformation require energy gain or loss. If we are changing a liquid to gas we heat it and that is how molecules of liquid gains energy and lattice spacing increases and bonds becomes weaker and thus gets converted to gas.
But we know that, if we lower the pressure of water (a closed container and evacuate air and so lowering pressure) and it start boiling even at 20degree C. from where it is getting energy for phase transformation?please help me if I am completely wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example of lowering the pressure above water, the water will only boil if you reduce the external pressure to below the vapour pressure of the water i.e. the water is superheated. The energy required to boil off the steam comes from the internal energy of the water, and as a result the water cools down. As the water cools, the vapour pressure will reduce until it matches the external pressure and at that point the water will stop boiling. If you reduce the pressure again the water will resume boiling, and will cool further.

This is basically the same process as [evaporative cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler) as invented by evolution when it developed sweat glands some millions of years ago (how many million depends on exactly what you mean by *sweat gland*).